# docker-compose.yml passing arg to build from file contents

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I would like to read contents of a file specified by an environment variable and pass it to docker-compose as build arg.
So then in my *Dockerfile* I can do:

```
ARG MY_FILE
RUN echo "$MY_FILE" > /my-file
```

This works perfectly:

```
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml build --build-arg MY_FILE="$(cat $PATH_TO_MY_FILE)"
```

However, if I try to do this in *docker-compose.yml* like so:

```
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - MY_FILE="$(cat $PATH_TO_MY_FILE)"
```

it fails with this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "build" option in service "my-service": "MY_FILE="$(cat $PATH_TO_MY_FILE)""
```

Any idea how do I have to construct this string to have the same effect? I tried $$ etc, but doesn't seem to work...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You will have to some pre-step before calling `docker-compose`, you can't avoid that anyhow.

Comment: Doing it at the command line works, just if I don't want to do it there and in *docker-compose.yml* instead it breaks

Comment: Docker compose doesn't support this, so you have to use a workaround only. Which would either mean pre-processing the compose file or generate the command you ran by reading the yaml and interpolating by generating the command in bash

Comment: Cool, thanks. If you put this as an answer I can then accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker compose doesn't support this, so you have to use a workaround only. Which would either mean pre-processing the compose file or generate the command you ran by reading the yaml and interpolating by generating the command in bash

You can use something like `yq` and parse the parameters from `docker-compose.yml` and generate your command. But honestly what you are doing right now is simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

In docker service 3, you can do that now.

```
web:
  image: xxxx
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

If you have specified a Compose file with `docker-compose -f FILE`, paths in env_file are relative to the directory that file is in.